# Use !reference or anchors with arguments in GitLab YAML

Tags: python, pip, gitlab, yaml, pipeline

In my GitLab YAML, I have several jobs that use the same basic command in their scripts but with different arguments. For example:

```yaml
stages:
  - lint

isort:
  stage: lint
  script:
    - pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --default-timeout=1000 isort
    - isort . --check-only --verbose

black:
  stage: lint
  script:
    - pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --default-timeout=1000 black
    - black . --check --verbose --diff --color
```

The `pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --default-timeout=1000` command is the same in every job but only the package name changes. (In my real code, this line is actually even longer and is used by several jobs multiple times, not just two once each)

I'd like to be able to define a macro/function within GitLab's YAML to allow me to **call this same line in each job with an argument for the package name**. I also **need to be able to call this multiple times within a job**, **and also have other code in the `script` section** before and after these calls.

Ideally, I'd kinda expect my code for the `isort` job to look like this:

```yaml
isort:
  stage: lint
  script:
    - *.my_pip_install isort   # or: !reference [.my_pip_install] isort
    - isort . --check-only --verbose
```

So far, I've tried a few approaches:

- Using `!reference` to reuse the command after I define it in a hidden job elsewhere e.g. inside `.my_pip_install`'s `script` section. I then reference it by using `!reference [.my_pip_install, script]` in my job. This would work except I can't find a way to pass the argument "isort" to the reference or append that string to the end of the call
- Using `!reference` with a variable. For example, the code for `.my_pip_install`'s `script` might be `pip install ... $PACKAGE`. Then in my calling job, I simply define my `variables` e.g. `PACKAGE = "isort"`. This partially works but I can't use this method more than once per job
- Using YAML anchors. I define a hidden script like with the `!reference` method but mark the end of the line with `&my_pip_install`. Then in my job's script I can use `*my_pip_install` or `<<: *my_pip_install` to have the code be placed in. This has two problems: I can't find a way to supply my argument, and -- if using the `<<:` method -- I can't have additional lines of code in my script
- Defining a bash function e.g. `my_pip_install (){ ...}` in the `default` `before_script`. This works when I call `my_pip_install "isort"` in my job scripts but it's hacky since this is outside of YAML/GitLab validation and checking. For example, in the runner logs the actual command is not shown when this function is executed, which makes debugging hard. It also doesn't show any substitution when viewing the "Merged YAML" tab in the GitLab Pipeline Editor. I'd prefer to use what's provided by GitLab/YAML in an elegant way for the pipeline

Comment: anchors and aliases are for representing the same object in multiple places. An alias doesn't take an argument. You should read up on the `<<` merge special key as it doesn't have to be the last entry in a YAML file, so you must be doing something wrong.  I don't think what you want to do can be done in YAML, so if possible you need either to use a template and generate (valid) YAML, or hope the program processing the YAML data loaded in specials ways that can satisfy your nead. You'll have more control over what happens with a YAML generating template.

Comment: The issue with the `<<` merge is not that I believe it ends the file, but that I'm not able to find a way to continue my `script:` section when it is used, including having text following that line (e.g. `<<: *pip_install isort`).